# Can I output resampling summary metrics when setting "LOOCV" for resampling in caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm using `caret` to fit some models, using `CV` or `LOOCV` for resampling. I wanted to output the model metrics and predictions also for the models built using the resamplings. When I use `trainControl(method = "cv", returnResamp = "all", savePredictions = "all")`, I do get an object containing this data, inside `object$pred` and `object$resample`. This does not happen, however, when using `trainControl(method = "LOOCV", returnResamp = "all", savePredictions = "all")`: `object$pred` only contains 1 iteration (I guess the final model) and `object$resample` is empty.

Is there any way to get these predictions and metrics for LOOCV?

Below I show the code I'm using.

```
# LOOCV
set.seed(99)
seedy <- lapply(1:(nrow(phy2)+1),function(x){sample.int(1000, 1)})

# Also set global resampling parameters
fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "LOOCV", # leave-one-out cross validation
  savePredictions = "all",
  returnResamp = "all",
  classProbs = T ,
  seed = seedy,
  summaryFunction = multiClassSummary
)

set.seed(99)
fit1 <- train(x = bty2,
                    y = phy2$grouping,
                    method = "lda", 
                    metric = "Kappa",
                    trControl = fitControl
)

# K-fold CV

index.folds <- createFolds(phy2$grouping, k = 5)
folds <- 5
fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "cv", # k-fold cross validation
  number = folds,
  savePredictions = "all",
  returnResamp = "all",
  classProbs = T ,
  seed = as.list(rep(99,folds+1)),
  summaryFunction = multiClassSummary,
  index = index.folds
)

set.seed(99)
fit2 <- train(x = bty2,
                 y = phy2$grouping,
                 method = "lda", 
                 metric = "Kappa",
                 trControl = fitControl
)
```